# What is Need of Google Play service and Advertisement ID when targeting Android OS 33. What is Location report

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I am updating my APP to target 33. Below are my queries:

1. Flurry doc says that we need to add Google Play service. What is the need of it.
2. Why we need Google Play server Advertisement ID in menifest ?
   I see that it worked without the Google Play service and Advertisement ID in manifest.

Follow up question is "withReportLocation"​ need to set explicitly to get Location report. But Location Report is same Geographical region which is shown in Flurry Dashboard ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Flurry Android SDK Release Notes, version 14.0.0. https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/releasenotes/android/#version-14-0-0-10-20-2022 , apps need to upgrade to 14.0.0 or above to,

**- Report device identifiers and location collection to be Google Policy Compliant.**

You don't need to add Google Play Service dependencies. However, adding Google Play server Advertisement ID (optional) will help to improve your Flurry Analytics data.

By default, location data is disabled to comply Google Policy. Yes, you need to use `withReportLocation` to enable the location data. And it will improve Geographical region features.